# What is the return type for movement variables like jump

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
public const ??? jump = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
```

What do I replace with the question marks with?

Comment: Whatever type [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) returns?

Comment: I want to be able to call Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) from another class using just jump

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment on my last reply (now deleted)... What exactly is stopping you from doing what you want to do?  It sounds like you should be starting with some introductory tutorials on C#.  Using types when declaring variables is very early functionality in any introduction to the language.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: @David (and OP) **you can't .. at all!** It is a `const` so the value assigned to it needs to be compile time constant .. which will **never** be the case for the return value of a runtime executed method call .... Is your goal to have a kind of shortcut alias?

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], so please do not use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921897/7111561) already explained totally correct: Regardless of the type (which is a `bool`) **you can't at all!**

You can't simply assign a method return value which is determined on **runtime** to a `const` which needs to be **compile time constant**.

However, if I am not totally wrong it seems to be that your actual goal is having some kind of **shortcut alias** for that call.

In this case you could have a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like

```
public static class Aliases
{
    public static bool jump => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
}
```

and then everywhere use e.g.

```
if(Aliases.jump)
```

instead.

If this has any further use over just using `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` though is highly doubtful...

Answer (score 1):

`Input.GetKey` and all the related methods are just `bool` types that tell you if a key has been pressed or not *on that particular frame*. You can't assign them to a constant because constants have to be defined when you compile your code, you can't assign any variable or method to a constant.

If you remove constant and just put `public bool jump` then you'll have a variable that's set to whatever `Input.GetKey` was on the frame you assigned it. So either it'll never change, or it'll just be an extra operation doing the same thing as writing `Input.GetKey()`.

You said you want to be able to call it from another class, but you can call `Input` methods from anywhere, they're static. If you're trying to synchronize what happens when you press the space key between scripts, then you can just check `Input.GetKey` in the `Update` method on both scripts. All updates run every frame for every activated script, so they'll always be seeing the same values from `Input`.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the signature of the method. It is

> public static bool GetKey(string name)

So I would tell you that you miss a bool type in place of ??? :)

Comment: It is still a `const` so it simply is impossible to assign a runtime return value of a method to it ...